# problem with pine editor decreasing volume

Tags: pine-script

[image]
I want it to give a warning if the volume is decreasing when the price comes back to the red area.

I tried to try but it didn't work

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
study(title="Para Basma", shorttitle="Para Basma", overlay=true)

// Inputs
pvtLenL       = input(3, minval=1, title="Pivot Uzunluğu Sol Taraf")
pvtLenR       = input(3, minval=1, title="Pivot Uzunluğu Sağ Taraf")


// Yüksek ve Düşük Pivot Noktaları Alın
pvthi_ = pivothigh(open, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)
yuksek=pivothigh(high, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)
pvtlo_ = pivotlow(close, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)

// Çizdirmeden önce Zorla Pivot tamamlama.
Shunt = 1 //Pivotu yazdırmadan önce kapanmayı bekle? 1 gerçek için 0 yanlış için
maxLvlLen = 0 //Maksimum Uzatma Uzunluğu
pvthi = pvthi_[Shunt]
pvtlo = pvtlo_[Shunt]


// Mevcut Pivot Seviyesi için kaç mum olduğunu sayın, Yeni sıfırlama durumunda.
counthi = barssince(not na(pvthi))
countlo = barssince(not na(pvtlo))
 
pvthis = fixnan(pvthi)
pvtlos = fixnan(pvtlo)
hipc = change(pvthis) != 0 ? na : color.maroon
lopc = change(pvtlos) != 0 ? na : color.green

deneme=crossover(high,pvthis) and high<yuksek
// Display Pivot lines
plot((maxLvlLen == 0 or counthi < maxLvlLen) ? pvthis : na, color=hipc, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLenR-Shunt, title="Top Levels")
plot((maxLvlLen == 0 or countlo < maxLvlLen) ? pvtlos : na, color=lopc, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLenR-Shunt, title="Bottom Levels")

plotshape(deneme, title="Overbought", location=location.belowbar, color=color.purple, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="AL")
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.